# How do I convert a multiprocessor.manager.list to a pure python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I have my normal script doing about 30,000 records in 20 seconds. Given that amount of data that I have to run through (over 50 million records), I thought it wise to use python's multiprocessing.

At the end of my process, I do a database update using sqlalchemy core where I update the processed records in batches of 50,000. [SQLAlchemy Core requires that you pass it a list for it to do a bulk update or even insert](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#executing-multiple-statements). I'll call this list `py_list`

For Python's multiprocessing, am capturing the results of the processes via a `multiprocessing.manager.list()` which I will call `mp_list`.

Everything works fine till the point that I pass the `mp_list` to the SQLAlchemy bulk update statement. This fails with the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`. Googling brings me to a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807925/1082673) which states that the multiprocessing.manager.list() and even a multiprocessing.manager.dict() is/are not a true python lists/dictionaries.

Question then is, how do I convert the multiprocessing.manager.list into a true python list.

`mp_list` is populated as follows:

```
import multiprocessing
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
mp_list = manager.list()

def populate_mp_list(pid, is_processed):
    '''Mark the record as having been processed'''
    dict = {}
    dict['b_id'] = pid
    dict['is_processed'] = is_processed
    mp_list.append(dict)
```

The SQLALchemy code throwing the error is as follows:

```
CONN = Engine.connect()
trans = CONN.begin()
stmt = mytable.update().where(mytable.c.id == bindparam('b_id')).\
values(is_processed=bindparam('is_processed'))
CONN.execute(stmt, mp_list)
trans.commit(
```

I've tried converting the mp_list into a true python list. The new list created works but the time penalty for its creation negates all the time saved in multiprocessing.

If I do a loop of the returned `mp_list` and create a new list.

```
y = []
for x in mp_list:
    y.append(x)
```

Also, if I do a "copy" of the `mp_list`, each copy adds a 3 seconds! penalty on average which ain't cool.

```
y = mp_list[0:len(mp_list)]
```

So, which would be the fastest way to convert the multiprocessing.manager.list into a list usable by SQLAlchemy Core?

Comment: What is in your `mp_list`? The error message suggests that it contains `list`s, when it needs to contain `dict`s (or, possibly, `multiprocessing.manager.dict`s). A pure Python `list` still won't have the attribute `keys`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've edited question to include how the `mp_list` is being generated and the sqlalchemy code that throws out the error.

Answer (score 6):

Hope i'm not late.

Doesn't this work?

```
pythonlist = list(mp_list)
```

Same thing works for dict too:-

```
pythondict = dict(mp_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the performance of:

y = [x for x in mp_list]

?

Comment: Not much improvement. It has the same time penalty like the two I've listed.

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution is taken by using list.

```
result_list = list(proxy_list)
```

Comment: in my case.. this operation freezes the code execution.