# KeyError when attempting to access a key value from a nested Manager.dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing

I have some multiprocessing code where I'd like to share a nested dictionary among processes. The dictionary is never modified by the processes; just read.

In the simplest form, the problematic code is as follows:

```python
from multiprocessing import Manager

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.delays = self.manager.dict({})

    def foo(self, types, keys):
        for type in types:
            self.delays[type] = self.manager.dict({})

            for key in keys:
                self.delays[type][key] = 0

                print("The delay is " + str(self.delays[type][key]))
```

I get a `KeyError` at the print statement where it says that the key I'm using does not exist. I'm not sure why this is happening, since I just inserted the key into the dict. When I change this into a regular dict, the problem goes away.

Comment: Would it be possible to post the relevant parts of `Manager` class? e.g. what is the difference between `Manager.dict()` and a plain old Python dict?

Comment: `Manager` is from the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Comment: Got it and edited just in case someone else got same question :)

Comment: It seems to be a known issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue6766

Comment: Manager.dict() is a dict `DictProxy` not an actual dict

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I know it's a proxy. What I'm not clear about is why the key I just added can't be accessed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807649/is-multiprocessing-manager-dict-setdefault-broken

Comment: This seems to be a problem only when nesting

Comment: Based on the other related question http://pastebin.com/30cXTWuE

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This seems to be non-obvious behavior, though. I can see the case if I just had `self.delays[type] = {}`, since it is a mutable object and the manager won't have any idea if it gets changed. Technically the managed dict is "mutable", but since it is itself a proxy that is controlled by the same manager, I would expect `self.delays[type][key]` to give me the managed dict instead of a *copy* of the managed dict, i.e., a copy of the *proxy*. Thanks for your workaround! If you add it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @VivinPaliath, no prob,  it is definitely not intuitive behaviour and the workaround seems very much like a hack but I don't know any other way around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10807976/2141635) to a related question, you can use a `Manager.list`  appending a dict, then use a reference to the dict:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.l = self.manager.list()
        self.l.append({})
        self.delays = self.l[0]

    def foo(self, types, keys):
        for type in types:
            self.delays[type] = self.manager.dict()
            for key in keys:
                self.delays[type].setdefault(key, 0)
                print("The delay is {}".format(self.delays[type][key]))
```